# ob_start() is partially capturing data

Tags: php, mysql, database, ob-start

I am using the following code:

PHP:

```
// Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(uniqid(rand(),true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();

$alphabet = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';    

function base_encode($num, $alphabet) {
    $base_count = strlen($alphabet);
    $encoded = '';

    while ($num >= $base_count) {

        $div = $num/$base_count;
        $mod = ($num-($base_count*intval($div)));
        $encoded = $alphabet[$mod] . $encoded;
        $num = intval($div);
    }

    if ($num) $encoded = $alphabet[$num] . $encoded;
        return $encoded;
}


function base_decode($num, $alphabet) {
    $decoded = 0;
    $multi = 1;

    while (strlen($num) > 0) {
        $digit = $num[strlen($num)-1];
        $decoded += $multi * strpos($alphabet, $digit);
        $multi = $multi * strlen($alphabet);
        $num = substr($num, 0, -1);
    }

    return $decoded;
}

// Ob start 
 ob_start();
 echo base_encode($Guid, $alphabet); //should output: bUKpk
 $theid = ob_get_contents();
 ob_get_clean();
```

The problem:

When I `echo $theid`, it shows the complete entry, but as it is being inserted into the database, only the first entry in the sequence gets inserted, for example for the entry `buKPK`, only 'b' is being inserted not the rest.

Comment: I get the expected result when I run this.

Comment: Me confused about the purpose of the ob_start workaround in that specific code. Why do you `echo` the result instead of assigning it directly?

Comment: I just assumed he was simplifying the code to isolate the problem.

Comment: @mario, because what is being echoed is being saved as an entry in the database.  Got a better idea? I am new to programmign so working with what i have learned from dummies book.

Comment: Replace the ob_start part with just `$theid = base_encode($Guid, $alphabet);` and if you need it printed out for the database (???) you can echo the variable still later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the character length in the database (i.e. if it is varchar(10) make sure you are not storing more than 10 characters in that field)

Comment: OK that did the trick, i was using int() instead of varchar... thanks shankhan.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ob_end_clean()` rather than `ob_get_clean()`. Successive calls to ob_start() create "nested" buffering contexts; `ob_get_clean()` fetches and clears the current context, but does not terminate it, so a second call to `ob_start()` creates a second nested buffering context. In this case, you just want to capture the output buffer and then terminate capture context.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Using that actually got me to get the second character but not anything after that.